# Why does my list reset when I press a button?

Tags: c#, wcf, html-lists

I have a page where a instructor inserts a student's id into a text box and then submits it. It should then come up with a list of all the students that have been added. But every time the submit button is pressed, the list gets cleared and only the last student added is displayed.

```
public Service1Client ws = new Service1Client();
public string adress;
public List<ServiceReference1.User> lu;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lu==null)
        lu= new List<ServiceReference1.User>();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference1.User u= new ServiceReference1.User();
    u = ws.ShowUser(int.Parse(TextBox2.Text));

    if (!IsContained(u))
    {
        lu.Add(u);
        TextBox1.Text += u.FirstName;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to solve this? Or must I send the information to the page via a query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each HTTP request gets a new instance of your page.
You should store the list in ViewState to persist across requests.